# Writing to the console after server:run

Tags: symfony

In Symfony, I am running php bin/console server:run, which prints some messages, as shown below:

```
jon@debian:~/Documents/SFLive-Paris2016-Workflow$ php bin/console server:run

 [OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000                                 


 // Quit the server with CONTROL-C.                                             

PHP 7.0.15-1~dotdeb+8.1 Development Server started at Tue Feb  7 21:14:00 2017
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000
Document root is /home/jon/Documents/SFLive-Paris2016-Workflow/web
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Tue Feb  7 21:28:05 2017] 127.0.0.1:45237 [200]: /
[Tue Feb  7 21:28:05 2017] 127.0.0.1:45240 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Feb  7 21:28:47 2017] 127.0.0.1:45244 [200]: /
[Tue Feb  7 21:28:47 2017] 127.0.0.1:45249 [200]: /_wdt/c2da7a
```

I have a handler that listens out user switching. It is defined in services.xml as:

```
    <service id="test.on_switch_user_success" class="AppBundle\EventListener\OnSwitchUserSuccessHandler">
        <argument type="service" id="twig" />
        <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="security.switch_user" method="onSwitchUser" />
    </service>
```

For completeness, OnSwitchUserSuccessHandler is:

```
<?php

namespace UserFlowBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\SwitchUserEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Workflow\Registry;


use Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleCommandEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Console\ConsoleEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;


class OnSwitchUserSuccessHandler {

    private $em;
    private $workflowRegstry;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, Registry $workflowRegistry)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->workflowRegistry = $workflowRegistry;
    }

    public function onSwitchUser(SwitchUserEvent $event) 
    {

        $repository = $this->em->getRepository('UserFlowBundle:LoginMessage');


        $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
        $dispatcher->addListener(ConsoleEvents::COMMAND, function (ConsoleCommandEvent $event) {

            // get the output instance
            $output = $event->getOutput();
           // write something about the command
           $output->writeln(sprintf('This is a console message: <info>%s</info>', $message));
        });

    }

}
```

How can I get onSwitchUser to write to the console output?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to log events is to use Monolog and accessing it through `/var/logs/dev.log` or use `dump()` ([VarDumper component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html)) function and trace all the dumps using profile.

If you really need to print out message to console you can make advantage of *ConsoleCommandEvent* interface.

<kbd>**AppBundle/EventListener/OnSwitchUserSuccessHandler.php**</kbd>

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\SwitchUserEvent;
use Twig_Environment as Environment;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleCommandEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Console\ConsoleEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;

class OnSwitchUserSuccessHandler {

    // ...

    public function onSwitchUser(SwitchUserEvent $event) 
    {
        $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
        $dispatcher->addListener(ConsoleEvents::COMMAND, function (ConsoleCommandEvent $event) {

         // get the output instance
         $output = $event->getOutput();

        // write something about the command
        $output->writeln(sprintf('This is a console message: <info>%s</info>', $message));
        }
    }

}


});
```

Comment: @Ginger if this answer solves your problem please accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, but nothing happens when I switch user. I know that onSwitchUser gets called as I can raise an exception in it.  updated my code sample above to show what I have.